# Boolean parameters - should I name them?

Tags: coding-style

so i just came across some code that reads like so:

```
checkCalculationPeriodFrequency("7D", "7D", SHOULD_MATCH);
```

and

```
checkCalculationPeriodFrequency("7D", "8D", SHOULD_NOT_MATCH);
```

Let's not worry about what the code does for now (or indeed, ever), but instead, let's worry about that last parameter - the SHOULD_MATCH and SHOULD_NOT_MATCH

Its something i've thought of before but thought might be "bad" to do (inasmuch as "bad" holds any real meaning in a postmodernist world).

above, those values are declared (as you might have assumed):

```
private boolean SHOULD_MATCH = true;
private boolean SHOULD_NOT_MATCH = false;
```

I can't recall reading about "naming" the boolean parameter passed to a method call to ease readability, but it certainly makes sense (for readability, but then, it also hides what the value is, if only a teeny bit). Is this a style thing that others have found is instagram or like, soooo facebook?

Comment: Depends what language; some languages have formatting guidelines that may specify the preferred way.

Comment: It is certainly much better than just `true` or `false`.

Comment: If the parameter name is clear, I think your way is overkill. I would suggest as an alternative to use enums if you want *named* values.

Comment: You can apply similar logic to the rest of the parameters - declare a `String whateverTheFirstParameterIs = "7D"`, and pass that to the function instead (it's often not clear what parameters refer to). But this feels like overkill. My point being, don't use `SHOULD_(NOT_)MATCH`.

Comment: You should name them, but give them obscure names nobody will understand. That way they'll have to read the manual. Better yet, don't write a manual so users are forced to parse the code mentally. They'll pay much more attention to your work the more obscure and tricky you are and, in the end they'll feel a sense of accomplishment at figuring things out. ;) Really, names are so facetagram! See http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/ for a language that "gets it".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Naming the argument would help with readability, especially when the alternative is usually something like

```
checkCalculationFrequency("7D",
                          "8D",
                          true /* should match */);
```

which is ugly. Having context-specific constants could be a solution to this.

I would actually go a step further and redefine the function prototype to accept an `enum` instead:

```
enum MatchType {
    ShouldMatch,
    ShouldNotMatch
};

void checkCalculationFrequency(string a, string b, MatchType match);
```

I would prefer this over a boolean, because it gives you flexibility to extend the function to accept other `MatchTypes` later.

Comment: +1 for example of enum. This is "the right way", even though writing the enum seems like a chore at first.

Comment: @slim Yes, it makes it easy to define a third enum, say `ShouldMaybeMatch`, later on that triggers new behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you not to do this way.

First, for each object, the two members SHOULD_MATCH and SHOULD_NOT_MATCH are regenerated. And that's not good because it's not a behavior of the object. So it you want to use is, at least describe it as STATIC FINAL.

Second, I prefer to use an enum instead, because you can control completely the value of the param, i.e. when you use it, you must use either SHOULD_MATCH or SHOULD_NOT_MATCH, not just true or false. And this increase the readability too.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed for readability.  The idea is that the reader of the function call might not know immediately what the value `true` mean in the function call, but `SHOULD_MATCH` conveys the meaning immediately (and if you need to look up the actual value, you can do so with not much effort).

This becomes even more understandable if you have more than one boolean parameters in the function call: which `true` means what?

The next step in this logic is to create named object values (e.g. via enum) for the parameter values: you cannot pass on the wrong value to the function (e.g. in the example of three boolean parameters, nothing stops me from passing in `SHOULD_MATCH` for all of them, even though it does not make sense semantically for that function).

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely more than a style thing.

We have a similar system that takes takes input from a switch in the form of boolean values, 1 or 0, which is pretty much the same as true or false.

In this system we declare our variables OPEN = true and CLOSED = false* and pass them into functions which perform different actions depending on the state of the switch. Now if someone happens to hook up the switch differently it may be that we now get the value 0 when it is OPEN and 1 when it is CLOSED.

By having named boolean variables we can easily adapt the system without having to change the logic throughout. The code becomes self documenting because developers can clearer see what action is meant to be taken in which case without worrying what value comes.

Of course the true purpose of the boolean value should be well documented else where and it is in our system....honest....

*(*maybe we use OPEN, !OPEN I forget)*